# Hector plugins for gazebo problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I use hector plugins with ros electric?
The command

> apt-get install
> ros-electric-hector-gazebo

doesn't work!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56459/hector-plugins-for-gazebo-problem/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacobsolid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1909/jacobsolid/) on 2013-05-24**:
it works for me very well, maybe you need to download it and run rosmake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably, the problem is that you are using a version of Ubuntu in which there is not this package in the repositories.

---

Originally posted by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) with karma: 223 on 2014-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0